# Connect to SQLite using C#

Tags: c#, ado.net, sqlite, parameter-passing

I got the following error:

> Input string was not in a correct format

Can anyone help to me? Here is my input parameters and method:

```
public void insertSQL(Dictionary<string,object> objects, string dbConnectionString)
{
    openConnection(dbConnectionString);

    SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(sqliteCon);
    command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO AppUser VALUES(@name, @surname)", objects, "Data Source=sample.s3db"
    command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

    foreach (var param in objects)
    {
        command.Parameters.Add(new SQLiteParameter(param.Key,SqlDbType.NVarChar){ Value =  (String)param.Value} );
        Console.WriteLine(command.Parameters.Count);
    }
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();     
    closeConnection();
}
```

Comment: On what line does the error occur? i.e. is it related to `sql` or `dbConnectionString`? So far we just know that any of the input strings was not correctly formatted.

Comment: You may need to specify columns. e.g. ( INSERT INTO AppUser Name, Surname VALUES (@name, @surname);....just a guess

Comment: I **Highly** recommend using http://code.google.com/p/dapper-dot-net/. I can't write sql the way this questions shows. I just cant

Comment: fyi the way to rewrite it in dapper is `sqliteCon.Execute("INSERT INTO AppUser VALUES(@name, @surname)", new {name=theName, @surname=theSurname});`. Yep all that code after open is a one liner.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper command.ExecuteNonQuery() gives the error.

Answer (score 2):

You must tell for which columns you are presenting values (other will get their default values)
Something like :

```
INSERT INTO AppUser (name,surname) VALUES(@name, @surname) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Parameters' name in query should be equal to parameters you assign values to:

```
using (SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection(connectionString))
using (SQLiteCommand command = new SQLiteCommand(connection))
{
    command.CommandText = "...";

    command.Parameters.Add("@name", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = name;
    command.Parameters.Add("@surname", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = value;

    connection.Open();
    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: @Roberto: On what value of key or its value do you get this error?